# Why am I getting a 'no-unused-var' error when using in an inline function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, eslint

Here's a snippent of my code:

```
const prevState = this.state;
this.setState(prevState => ({
  companies_checked: {
    ...prevState.companies_checked,
    [target.value]: target.checked
  }
}));
```

It is generating the following error:

```
Line 52:  'prevState' is assigned a value but 
never used  no-unused-vars
```

I'm using the variable in the inline/arrow function. What's the best way to make the error go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (i.e. remove the line where you declare `prevState`):

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  companies_checked: {
    ...prevState.companies_checked,
    [target.value]: target.checked
  }
}));
```

Eslint is complaining that you have declared the constant `prevState` without ever using it, afterwards. The correct way to fix the problem is to simply not declare it in the first place.

The `prevState` inside your `setState` call is correct - the first argument `setState` sends to your callback function is the previous state, and this is the one you want to use inside the callback function.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using the variable in the inline/arrow function.

No, you don't. The `prevState` that you use in the function is declared as the function's parameter. It is shadowing the `const`-declared `prevState` from the outer scope.

> What's the best way to make the error go away?

Assuming the function is working as is, just omit the `const` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is just naming conflict.

```
  // you already declared prevState
    const prevState = this.state;
    // change to this.setState(previousState => 
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      companies_checked: {
        ...prevState.companies_checked,
        [target.value]: target.checked
      }
    }));
```

You actually did not use prevState that you declared

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I forgot that arrow functions had access to the outer context. I'll mark your answer as correct, but to make it even blunter can you replace 'this.setState(prevState =>' with 'this.setState( () =>' ?

Comment: Can you just use this.setState({ ...this.state.companies_checked, [target.value]: target.checked}) ? If its not like real time related project, just using setState should be fine.

Comment: Sure, even better

Comment: This isn't a naming conflict, and the proposed solution isn't the correct one. The correct solution would be to delete `const prevState = this.state;` and leave everything else as is. The problem is that `prevState` is declared and never used, thus `eslint` complains about the unused variable. The solution is to not declare the variable in the first place, since it will never be used.

Comment: Your second comment may get rid of the eslint error, but it doesn't fix the actual mistake in the code.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it suggests an incorrect usage of `setState`. The first argument to `setState` is usually an updater function. The first parameter sent to the updater function by `setState` is the previous state. The correct way to solve the problem is to remove the erroneous `prevState` declaration and use the previous state argument sent to the updater function by `setState`. Following the advice in this answer will lead to non standard behavior. It is likely to appear to work in some cases, but will break in many other cases.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation Tex, I changed the correct mark and feel much smarter :)